# Почему указатель не нулевой или как портировать функцию с плюсов

Tags: c, указатели, структуры

Есть структура на плюсах

```
struct node // структура для представления узлов дерева
{
    int key;
    unsigned char height;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node(int k) { key = k; left = right = 0; height = 1; }
};
```

И функция:

```
node* insert(node* p, int k) // вставка ключа k в дерево с корнем p
{
    if( !p ) return new node(k);
    if( k<p->key )
        p->left = insert(p->left,k);
    else
        p->right = insert(p->right,k);
    return balance(p);
}
```

Я сделал следующий код:

```
struct avlleaf { // структура для представления узлов дерева
    char key[256];                                // Ключ
    unsigned long long int llupar;                // Числовой параметр
    unsigned char height;                         // Высота
    struct avlleaf* left;                        // Левый ребенок
    struct avlleaf* right;                       // Правый ребенок
};
```

И 2е функции:

```
/ Создание
void init_tree(struct avlleaf* p, char key[256]) {
  unsigned long long t;
  for (t = 0; t < 256; t++) {
        p->key[t] = key[t];
      }
  p->left = p->right = NULL;
  p->height = 1;
}

// Добавление
struct avlleaf* insert_tree(struct avlleaf* p, char key[256]) { // вставка ключа k в дерево с корнем p
    if (!p){
     p = malloc(sizeof (struct avlleaf));
     init_tree(p, key);
     return p;
    }

    if (strcmp(key, p->key) >  0)
        p->left = insert_tree(p->left,key);
    else if (strcmp(key, p->key) <  0)
        p->right = insert_tree(p->right,key);
    else {
        printf("Exist\n");
        return p;
    }

    return rebalance(p);
}
```

В main я использую следующие строки:

```
struct avlleaf *tree;
tree = NULL;
tree = insert_tree(tree, tmpkey);
```

Так вот, на строке:

```
if (!p){
```

Он программа не реагирует.
Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Обнулить при инициализации `tree` - в нем же мусор! И еще - подозрительно, что вы не сохраняете возвращаемое `insert_tree(tree, tmpkey);` значение - т.е. вы его просто теряете (значение переменной `tree` вне функции остнется неизменным).

Comment: @Harry а как обнулять - я пробывал приравнивать к NULL, не помогло

Comment: @Harry Можете поправить - как правильнее сделать, чтоб ничего не терятьт

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что у вас `if (!p)` для `p==NULL` не отрабатывает? Простите, поверить не могу. Могу поверить. что вы не прочли (или не поняли) мой ответ и считаете, что после `struct avlleaf *tree = NULL;
insert_tree(tree, tmpkey);` значение `tree` должно измениться - так еще раз перечитайте, что я вам написал...

Comment: 1) Переписал кол

Comment: struct avlleaf *tree;

Comment: tree = NULL; ______

Comment: tree = insert_tree(tree, tmpkey);

Comment: @Harry, странно - компилирую в Boardland - проскакивает условие
Сейчас попробовал в Linux gcc - все работает

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: "компилирую в Boardland - проскакивает условие" - вы описываете какое-то "магическое" поведение, вызванное скорее всего тем, что вы компилируете не то, что нам тут показываете.